# Let G be a group and let H and N be subgroups of G such that N is a normal subgroup of G. Then, How come H∩N is a subgroup of H?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

[ Theorem: Let G be a group and let H and N be subgroups of G such that N is a normal subgroup of G

Then, H∩N is normal subgroup of H ]

The proof of this theorem starts by saying that from the properties of intersection and union of subgroups, we can see that H∩N which is a subset of H is also a subgroup of H and then it builds upon this to go on to prove the stated theorem.

I'm having trouble understanding this line. Could somebody please elucidate it ?

Comment: Any intersection of subgroups of $G$ is also a subgroup. If you don't know this, try to prove it. (it is very easy)

Comment: **Next do this:** For any $h\in H$ and any $x\in H\cap N$ we have $hxh^{-1}$ as $H$ is group and $x,h$ both are in $H$; similarly $hxh^{-1}\in N$ as $x\in N$ and $N$ is normal in $G$. Note that $h\in H\implies h\in G$ as $H$ is a subset of $G$. So, $hxh^{-1}\in H\cap N$ for all $h\in H$ and for all $x\in H\cap N$. Therefore, $H\cap N$ is normal in $H$.

Comment: Which "line" are you having trouble understanding: subgroup or normality?

Comment: @Mark  I know this. But if H and N are subgroups of G then their intersection is a subgroup of G (and not H, right ?) but it says that says their intersection is a subgroup of H too. Where does that come from ?

Comment: @Pishachadhipati $H$ being a subgroup of $G$ means that $H$ is a subset, and it is itself a group with respect to the restriction of the operation of $G$. So it easily follows that if $H,K$ are subgroups of $G$ and $K\subseteq H$ then $K$ is a subgroup of $H$.

Comment: @Mark I now get it. It feels stupid that I missed such a basic thing haha. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2):

If $H_1,H_2\le G$, then $H_1\cap H_2\le G$.
Infact $1_G\in H1\le G$ and $1_G\in H_2\le G\implies1_G\in H_1\cap H_2$.
If $x\in H_1\cap H_2$, then it will exist the inverse of $x$ because both $H_1$ and $H_2$ are subgroups of $G$, so they are closed under inverse. 
If $x,y\in H_1\cap H_2\implies xy\in H_1$ and $xy\in H_2$, so $xy\in H_1\cap H_2.$

Now we want to show that if $N\trianglelefteq G$ and $H\le G\implies H\cap N\trianglelefteq H$.
Let $x$ be an element of $H\cap N$ and let $h$ be a generic element of $H$. Since $N$ is normal in all $G$, it is also normal in any subgroup of $G$. In other words $g^{-1}ng\in N$ $\forall g\in G,\forall n\in N\implies h^{-1}xh\in N$ $\forall x\in H\cap N$ and $\forall h\in H$. But the product $h^{-1}xh$ also belongs to $H$, then $h^{-1}xh\in H\cap N\implies H\cap N\trianglelefteq H$.